# Upload Files In Spring misses jar file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, war

I tried to have an upload option for my spring web app, and I add following resolver

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000"></property>
 </bean>
```

I also included two jar files in my WEB-INF/lib folder: commons-fileupload-1.3.jar and commons-io-2.4.jar. But when I run it, it still reports the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)
```

WHat am I still missing? I checked that the FileItemFactory is indeed in my Web App Library.

Thanks

Comment: Seems that your application server is caching the WAR file and not updating it with the latest generated WAR. Clean your deploy folder and redeploy your app.

Comment: Thanks, but where is deploy folder. I am using Mac, and I can't find workspace/.metadata folder, which suppose to contain the deployment

Comment: Which application server are you using? Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish...?

Comment: I use Tomcat. And I found the deployment folder, delete them, ad deployed it again, but the problem still persist. I can see my jar files are deployed into the WEB-INF/lib folder, but error still reports no FileItemFactory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I put some of the jar files to my tomcat common shared lib folder, and some to my WEB-INF/lib folder. I moved everything to my webapp lib folder, and now it works fine.